# Rails: Getting timestamp when user visits "new" page (and save it into the database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timestamp

I want to save the timestamp when a user visits the posts#new page (.../posts/new) for the first time and save this timestamp in the posts table in the database.

**What I've done so far**

1. In the posts table, I've added and migrated a column named first_time_visit which has the datatype timestamp
2. In my posts_controller.rb I've initialised a @post with the first_time_visit attribute set to Time.now
3. I have already whitelisted the "first_time_visit" attribute.

**Problem:**

- After creating and saving a new post, the first_time_visit column is still "nil".

In my posts_controller.rb

```
def new 
  @post = Post.new(first_time_visit: Time.now)
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Post saved."
  else
    render 'new', notice: "Post could not be saved."
  end
end

...

private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :link, :first_time_visit)
end
```

**I've also tried another solution:**

In my post.rb model:

```
def add_first_time_visit(time)
  self.first_time_visit = time
end
```

In my posts_controller.rb:

```
def new 
  @post = Post.new
  @post.add_first_time_visit(Time.now)
end
```

But this solution also only gives me a "nil".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `first_time_visit` to your form as hidden field.

By Rails' convention you should name your datetime field with `at` in the end. `first_time_visit` => `first_time_visited_at`

Comment: Argh, I feel so stupid, of course a hidden field worked, thanks. I added <%= hidden_field :first_time_visit, value = Time.current %> to my form.  However I guess your second suggestion would not work the way I want it? Because it will add the time the post is created and not the time the user visits the /posts/new page?

Comment: You're the second suggestion will not work in your case. Remove it from answer.

Comment: Too you can save `first_time_visit` into session and extract it in `create` action.